# Hoe to get core_config_data table value in checkout_index_index.xml file?

Tags: magento2.3.4

i have installed one custom extension, i have to modify it, i create `system.xml` file in this extension,
that file has a two textbox value, that i get in `checkout_index_index.xml` file, how to get it, please help me in this, thanks,

here is my system.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
    <tab id="bodak_checkout_custom_form" translate="label" sortOrder="0">
        <label>FMS Taxrelief</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="checkoutcustomform" translate="label"  sortOrder="100"  showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <class>checkout-custom-form</class>
        <label>Taxrelief</label>
        <tab>bodak_checkout_custom_form</tab>
        <resource>Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm::checkoutcustomform_config</resource>
        <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1">
                <label>Module Enable</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
            <field id="tax_state" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Tax State</label>
                <source_model>Bodak\CheckoutCustomForm\Model\Config\TaxState</source_model>
            </field>

            <field id="text_above_tax_number" translate="label" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Text above tax number</label>
            </field>
            <field id="text_above_tax_state" translate="label" sortOrder="4" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Text above tax state</label>
            </field>

        </group>
    </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**checkout_index_index.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/js/view/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Bodak_CheckoutCustomForm/checkout/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="custom-checkout-form-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-checkout-form-fields</item>
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                <item name="checkout_buyer_name" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Buyer name</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_buyer_email" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/email</item>
                                                                                        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">We will send an order confirmation to this email address</item>
                                                                                        </item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_buyer_email</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Buyer email</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="validate-email" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_purchase_order_no" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_purchase_order_no</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Purchase order no.</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">3</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_goods_mark" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/input</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_goods_mark</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Goods mark</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">4</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                                <item name="checkout_comment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/textarea</item>
                                                                                        <item name="cols" xsi:type="string">15</item>
                                                                                        <item name="rows" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customCheckoutForm.checkout_comment</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Comment</item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">5</item>
                                                                                </item>
                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]
in this code has two field name `text_above_tax_number` and `text_above_tax_state` that fields database value i want to get in my xml file,

I have try this [Link](https://www.rohanhapani.com/magento-2-get-config-value-in-layout-xml/) but in checkout_index_idex.xml file has how to add code i dont know

Comment: Can you specify in detail what you are looking for?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya in my checkout_index_index.xml file has written two field code, that field display at frontend, and i have created system.xml file and that file has also two field, now i want get that two field data in xml file

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i have upload my checkout_index_index.xml file code

Comment: Do you want to show those title on checkout page any where or something?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes i want two show that title in checkout page, above Buyer name and Goods mark field

Comment: @DhirenVasoya it is possible that, we get core_config_data table value display in xml file?